# how to fix this location could not be displayed error on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I'm pretty new to `Linux`, and I have 2 normal `NTFS` partitions everything was working fine and I can easily mount and use both portions from `Ubuntu Linux`. but one day I was deleting a huge file from one of the mounted partitions, by mistake I used the dismount command on this partition while the file was being deleted, whenever I try to remount it, I get this error :

```
this location could not be displayed :
sorry couldn't display all the content of "data": Error when getting information for file "the_path_to _the_file_it_was_being_deleted"
```

Comment: `sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdaX` - where X - number your ntfs-partition

Comment: And, if the above doesn't fix it, you'll have to repair it in Windows with Windiows tools. If you don't have Windows you shouldn't keep NTFS partitions around.